# Thread does nothing after 2 minutes

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I need to capture thumbnails of apsx forms which I am able to do with the below code.But the problem is I have around 12000 forms to be captured and my code runs for about 2 minutes and captures like 1500 thumbnails and stops executing without giving any Exception or Error.
Please help.

```
    private Bitmap GenerateThumbnail(string Url, int BrowserWidth, int BrowserHeight,    int ThumbnailWidth, int ThumbnailHeight)
    {
        this.Url = Url;
        this.BrowserWidth = BrowserWidth;
        this.BrowserHeight = BrowserHeight;
        this.Height = ThumbnailHeight;
        this.Width = ThumbnailWidth;

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GenerateThumbnailInteral));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        return ThumbnailImage;
    }
    private void GenerateThumbnailInteral()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser.Navigate(this.Url);
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
        while (webBrowser.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        }
        webBrowser.Dispose();
    }
    private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser = (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)sender;
        webBrowser.ClientSize = new Size(this.BrowserWidth, this.BrowserHeight);
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        this.ThumbnailImage = new Bitmap(webBrowser.Bounds.Width, webBrowser.Bounds.Height);
        webBrowser.BringToFront();
        webBrowser.DrawToBitmap(ThumbnailImage, webBrowser.Bounds);
        this.ThumbnailImage = (Bitmap)ThumbnailImage.GetThumbnailImage(Width, Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        this.ThumbnailImageSmall = (Bitmap)ThumbnailImage.GetThumbnailImage(200, 200, null, IntPtr.Zero);
    }       
    private void SaveImageThumbnail(List<FormClass> objFormClass)
    {
        try
        {
            string url = string.Empty;
            string folderName = string.Empty;
            foreach (FormClass form in objFormClass)//12000 forms
            {
                InternetSetCookie(url, authCookieName, authCookieValue);
                InternetSetCookie(url, "RP_si", rsiCookieValue);                    
                filepath = "D:\\Previews\\";
                folderName = form.FormId.ToString();
                url = string.Format("http://localhost/CRM/Sockets/{0}", form.FileName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(filepath + folderName))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath + folderName);
                }
                Bitmap image = GenerateThumbnail(url, 1024, 700, 600, 500);
                image.Save(string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}-medium.jpg", filepath, folderName, form.FormId), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);                    
            }
        }
         catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Logger.Error("Unhandled Exception", exp);
        }
    }
    public bool SaveThumbnails(string filePath, string authCookieName, string authCookieValue, string rpsiCookieValue)
    {
        this.authCookieName = authCookieName;
        this.authCookieValue = authCookieValue;
        this.rsiCookieValue = rpsiCookieValue;
        this.filepath = filePath;            
        try
        {
            List<FormClass> globalForms = formRepo.GetForms().ToList();//Returns 12000 forms from database
            SaveImageThumbnail(globalForms.ToList());
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);                
        }
    }
```

From Controller I call this method like this.

```
    public void SaveThumbnailImage(string Guid)
    {
        try
        {
            var formsService = SvcUnityContainer.DefaultContainer.WithStandardMappings().Resolve<IFormsService>();
            new Thread(() => formsService.SaveThumbnails("D:\\Previews\\", FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value, HttpContext.Request.Cookies["RP_si"].Value)).Start();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Logger.Error(exp.Message, exp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it run out of memory? (`Bitmap image = GenerateThumbnail..`) Does your exception log contain any errors also? you seem to be catching `Exception`s, and it could well be that there are `InnerExceptions` that you are doing nothing with

Comment: sounds like a memory issue. .  .

Comment: I would firstly look to declare any disposable objects in using blocks, secondly probably extract the content of the foreach loop to a separate method (for readability) and maybe parallelize this loop.  Probably a memory issue though

Comment: Let me try your suggestions I will update with the result

Comment: 600 x 500 x 1500 = 450000000 pixels  that is 1350 mega bytes of pixel data (3 bytes per pixel). You are running out of memory :) Disposing the Bitmaps is vital in this case.

Comment: After saving around 1500 forms images the webbrowser.readystate is always Uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

600 x 500 x 1500 = 450000000 pixels, that is 1350 megabytes of pixel data (3 bytes per pixel).

The process is running out of memory.

Disposing the Bitmaps is vital. You will run into a delay once the all memory is claimed and the Garbage Collector kicks in to free it but the process should continue after a bit.

Change this:

```
Bitmap image = GenerateThumbnail(url, 1024, 700, 600, 500);
image.Save(
    string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}-medium.jpg", filepath, folderName, form.FormId),
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

to this:

```
using(Bitmap image = GenerateThumbnail(url, 1024, 700, 600, 500))
{
    image.Save(
        string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}-medium.jpg", filepath, folderName, form.FormId),
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

On a side note: you might want to consider re-using the same web browser, that might help in speeding up the program. Instantiating and disposing the web browser 1500 times in a row might be a waste of time if you can (cleanly) re-use it.

Comment: I added a note on the re-use of the web browser control.

Comment: while (webBrowser.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
Here the readyState is always uninitialized so it goes in an infinite loop

Comment: @user3541013 - I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say. The line `foreach (FormClass form in objFormClass)//12000 forms` creates 1200 threads, each thread creates its own webbrowser.

Comment: foreach (FormClass form in objFormClass)//12000 forms means objFormClass is a list of 12000 objects of FormClass

Comment: @user3541013 - Yes and for each form this loop creates a browser